# Does Rails allow custom transaction commit and rollback ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As part of a single ActiveRecord transaction (I'm using a PostgreSQL db), I want to have regular non-database code that executes only upon successful transaction commit or rollback. I envision passing some sort of procs to `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` that will execute the appropriate one depending on transaction commit or rollback. I'm new to Rails and am wondering if such a functionality is offered?

The general problem I'm trying to solve is sending web requests to a third party service only if my own "process" is successful, but also being able to "rollback" network calls (via a separate, rollback request) if a transaction fails.

Comment: maybe use model call backs such as `after_save`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Individual records can define [after_commit and after_rollback callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks) which will fire after a transaction is committed or rolled back. They can also be tailored to particular actions such as creating or destroying a record.

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  after_commit :cleanup_that_thing, on: :destroy
  after_rollback :the_thing_wont_die, on: :destroy

  private def cleanup_that_thing
    ...
  end

  private def the_thing_wont_die
    ...
  end
end
```

At the individual transaction level, you'd use the normal [begin/rescue/else](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html).

```
begin
  YourModel.transaction do
    ...
  end
rescue
  # it didn't work
else
  # it did work
end
```